# При вводе значения после каждого третьего знака с конца поставить запятую

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Вот HTML

```
<input class="rangeInput" type="number" name="range_min" id="range_min" />
```

При загрузки страницы в инпуте с type="number" запятая не отображает число. Нужно чтобы пользователь мог вводить только числа и запятую. Пытался через JS это сделать.

Вот JS

```
$(".rangeInput").each(function() {
  str = $(this).val();
  res = format(str);
  $(this).val(res);
});

function format(str) {
    const s = str.length;
    const chars = str.split('');
    const strWithSpaces = chars.reduceRight((acc, char, i) => {
        const spaceOrNothing = ((((s - i) % 3) === 0) ? ',' : '');
        return (spaceOrNothing + char + acc);
    }, '');
    return ((strWithSpaces[0] === ',') ? strWithSpaces.slice(1) : strWithSpaces);
}
```

Но значение в инпутах все равно не отображается. Как это сделать?

Comment: в таком типе инпута нельзя писать несколько запятых.... т.к. там decimal формат... то есть одна точка или одна запятая.....ставь тип text

Comment: Ставил, но мне нужно запретить ввод буквенных символов.

Comment: ну это можно делать точно так же, как и разрешать запятые)) т.е. через скрипт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сделал так, что человек может вводить только цифру, а не цифру и запятую. Запятая ставится и убирается автоматически:

- Если последний символ в строке НЕ цифра, то убираю этот символ
- Если последний символ в строке цифра, то разделя. его посимвольно и убираю запятые, потому что их буду вставлять вручную заново
- Далее циклом иду по этим символам с конца, но т.к. я мутирую этот массив, то следить за `i` трудно, потому завёл счётчик `k`, который следит за тем, сколько символов я прошёл и если прошёл 3 штучки, то ставлю запятую, там где щас `i`:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#range_min');

input.addEventListener('input', () => {  
  const value = input.value;
  const lastSymbol = value.at(-1);
  const onlyNumberRegExp = /\d/;
  const delimeter = ',';
  
  if (!onlyNumberRegExp.test(lastSymbol)) {
    input.value = value.slice(0, value.length - 1);
    
    return;
  }
  
  let digitsWithoutComma = value.split('').filter(x => x !== delimeter);
  
  for(let i = digitsWithoutComma.length - 1, k = -2; i > 0; --i, ++k) {
    
    if (k % 3 === 0)
      digitsWithoutComma.splice(i, 0, delimeter);
  }
  
  input.value = digitsWithoutComma.join('');
})
```

```html
<input id="range_min" />
```

*[Предложил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1516842/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e/1516859?noredirect=1#comment2723420_1516859) эту идею [Oliver Patterson](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/423297/oliver-patterson)*

Так же можно решить эту задачу с помощью [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat)

Отличие от предыдущего алгоритма - отсутсвие цикла:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#range_min');

input.addEventListener('input', () => {  
  const value = input.value;
  const lastSymbol = value.at(-1);
  const onlyNumberRegExp = /\d/;
  const delimeter = ',';
  
  if (!onlyNumberRegExp.test(lastSymbol)) {
    input.value = value.slice(0, value.length - 1);
    
    return;
  }
  
  let numberWithoutComma = value.split('').filter(x => x !== delimeter).join('');  
  
  input.value = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(numberWithoutComma);
})
```

```html
<input id="range_min" />
```

Comment: При наборе 5000 не могу поставить запятую после 5(

Comment: @Denis Я невнимательно прочитал условие, простите. Я сделал так, чтобы после каждого третьего знака была запятая, а вам нужно было с конца. Как исправлю дам вам знать

Comment: Может стоит использовать [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat)?

Comment: @Denis Готово. Скоро добавлю вариант с `Intl.NumberFormat` как предлагал Oliver Patterson

Comment: Воспользовался вашим первым исправленным вариантом. Спасибо большое за помощь - очень помогло!!!!!